# Denoting the Conditional Minimum

Tags: notation

This questions concerns notation. I have a $2\times n$ matrix $X$. Is there a smooth way to denote the minimum of the $2$nd row conditional on elements in the first row being equal to some constant $c$. For example if $$X = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0.7 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.1\end{array}\right)$$ then for $c = 0$ is the demanded minimum $0.5$ (and $0.1$ for $c = 1$).

Background: I am parsing sequentially through a list. Every list entry that satisfies $k$ conditions (in the example there is only 1 condition, the first row), I want to delete those entries for which another variable (in the example the second row) is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Simply spelling out the set over which you want to take the minimum seems reasonable.  For example, write your matrix $X$ as $X = (x_{ij})_{2\times n}$, where $x_{ij}$ is the entry in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of $X$.  Then, for a fixed value of $c$, you are trying to determine the minimal element of the second row such that the entry just above that is $c$.  In notation, something like
$$
\min\{ x_{2j} : x_{1j} = c \},
\qquad
\min\{ x_{2j} \mid x_{1j} = c \}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\min_{x_{1j}=c} x_{2j}
$$
gets the job done.